# How to deploy docker-compose solution automatically from github to vps over ssh?

Tags: github, ssh, deployment, docker-compose, vps

What I want to do:
Deploy docker-compose solution from Github to my virtual private server which has docker and docker-compose installed.

I saw that there are Github Actions that allow me to copy files over SSH after push to master, but I don't know how to run `docker-compose up` on my server after source has been copied.

On my VPS I have Ubuntu 18.4 installed.

Answer (score 10):

I believe Github actions also allow you to run arbitrary commands on remote servers via ssh (there are [a few in their library](https://github.com/marketplace?utf8=%E2%9C%93&type=actions&query=ssh)).

Assuming you copy your `docker-compose.yml` into, `/home/user/app/docker-compose.yml`, you could run a command like so:

```
ssh user@yourserver.example.com "cd /home/user/app/ && docker-compose up -d"
```